# Filtering incoming messages based on a domain while excluding an address from that same domain

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In Gmail, if there are multiple accounts from the same domain name (e.g. name1@school.edu, name2@school.edu, etc.), you can create a filter that includes all of them using

```
from:(school.edu)
```

I am trying to create a filter that tags incoming messages from my school's domain.  Since my address also includes the same domain I want the filter to exclude it.

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
from:(school.edu - myself@school.edu)

from:(school.edu) - from:(myself@school.edu)

from:(school.edu) & (- from:(myself@school.edu))
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.  Turns out that when using the "-" operator, you can't have a space after it.

The following doesn't work:

```
from:(school.edu - myself@school.edu)
```

This does:

```
from:(school.edu -myself@school.edu)
```